# Number of ways of choosing n, m elements from non-disjoint sets A and B?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to choose $m$ and $n$ elements from (potentially non-disjoint) sets $A$ and $B$, respectively?

---

If the sets were disjoint, this would be $\binom{|A|}{m} \binom{|B|}{n}$.

If they aren't necessarily disjoint however, I can't seem to think of a nice closed-formula.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well iterate over the elements in the intersection, let say that $c=|A\cap B|$
$$\sum _{k=0}^{c}\binom{c}{k}\binom{|B|-c}{n-k}\binom{|A|-c}{m-k}$$

Comment: Thanks @Phicar, I'm not sure if this question will be removed as a duplicate, but if you want I'll accept an answer with this content from you

Comment: Sure Colin, glad to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As asked by the OP: Well iterate over the elements in the intersection, let say that $c=|A\cap B|$
$$\sum _{k=0}^{c}\binom{c}{k}\binom{|B|-c}{n-k}\binom{|A|-c}{m-k}.$$