# Number of ways of choosing n or more elements, and m or more elements from non-disjoint sets A and B?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to choose $m$ or more elements from set $A$ and $n$ or more elements from set $B$, given $|A \cap B| > 0$?

---

I have asked a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3754900/number-of-ways-of-choosing-n-m-elements-from-non-disjoint-sets-a-and-b) for choosing exactly $n$, $m$ elements from $A$, $B$ respectively.

Using the answer from the above question (in which $c = |A \cap B|$), I would believe the answer to this question is:

$$\sum_{i=m}^{|A|}\sum_{j=n}^{|B|}\sum _{k=0}^{c}\binom{c}{k}\binom{|B|-c}{i-k}\binom{|A|-c}{j-k}$$

Any confirmation or alternative answers would be appreciated.

Comment: That is almost correct. The $i,j$ in the summand (not the limit) should switch.

Comment: Oh of course, thanks very much

Comment: @user10354138 If you would like to post this comment as an answer I'll accept