# Number of subsets $S \subset A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... A_n$ where $|S \cap A_i| = a_i$?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, closed-form, np-complete

Given potentially non-disjoint sets $A_1, A_2, ... A_n$, how many subsets $S \subset \bigcup A_i$ exist where

$$|S \cap A_i| = a_i$$
for $0 < i \leq n$.

---

For $n = 1$, the answer is $\binom{A_1}{a_1}$

For $n = 2$, the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3754900/number-of-ways-of-choosing-n-m-elements-from-non-disjoint-sets-a-and-b?noredirect=1#comment7723409_3754900) is $\sum _{k=0}^{|A_1 \cap A_2|}\binom{|A_1 \cap A_2|}{k}\binom{|A_1|-|A_1 \cap A_2|}{a_1-k}\binom{|A_2|-|A_1 \cap A_2|}{a_2-k}$

However, is there a general result for a general $n$ (possibly a recurrence relation)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that this problem is NP-hard, so I would not expect a very clean formulation for general $n$ (certainly not one that is efficiently solvable).

Comment: @MeesdeVries do you mean #P?

Comment: @MeesdeVries thank you very much, and you too user1001001. Do you know if there is a name for this specific NP / #P problem (let's say it's #P for the moment given it's a counting problem)? In any case, I'll accept an answer with such an explanation. If you could possibly expand on why it's #P in the answer that would be great, but not necessary

Comment: @user1001001, I meant NP-hard, or more precisely that determining whether the answer is non-zero is an NP-complete problem. I wouldn't be surprised if this was #P-complete, but I don't know enough about complexity theory to confidently assert that.

Comment: @MeesdeVries if you would like to answer this question by stating that this problem is most likely #P-Hard or #P-Complete, I think that would be acceptable